# Как подключить Proxy в Python для парсинга с asyncio?

Tags: python, proxy, асинхронность, aiohttp

Всем привет. Такой фрагмент кода:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_market_price(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, crypto: str):
    async with session.get('https://link.ru/users') as response:
       ...
```

Мне нужно подключить к нему прокси. Как это сделать?

Я пробую так:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

proxy = '173.245.49.70:80'

async def get_market_price(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, crypto: str):
    async with session.get('https://link.ru/users', proxy=proxy) as response:
       ...
```

Но это не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Поправил. Оставил часть кода, которая относится к вопросу

Comment: Хорошо, так нормально

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Нужно просто добавить http

```
proxy = "http://173.245.49.70:80"
```